# Using List<string> in SXA rendering variant

Tags: sxa

I have a CustomHeroViewModel class

```
public class CustomHeroViewModel : VariantsRenderingModel
{
    public string HeroTitle { get; set; }
    public string HeroDescription { get; set; }
    public List<string> ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the Model field in the Rendering Variant and I am able to get HeroTitle and HeroDescription Model fields in the Rendering Variant.

[image]

ImageUrl field is the List of string. How can I loop through ImageUrl and use it in the Rendering Variant?

Has anyone done something similar to that? Any help or recommendation would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of SXA are you using?

Comment: 11000 @RichardSeal

Comment: have a look at this article - https://olmecdev.com/2019/The-SXA-Way-Advanced-Rendering-Variants/

Comment: @GauravAgarwal thanks that answer my question. I also tried to use Scriban as well. I wanted to print the HeroTitle property like {{o_model.HeroTitle}} but it shows no result. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this might not be possible at the moment. This feature initially was designed to work with strongly typed models so you can work around it by having:

```
public class CustomHeroViewModel : VariantsRenderingModel
{
    public string HeroTitle { get; set; }
    public string HeroDescription { get; set; }
    public List<MyImage> Images { get; set; }
}

public class MyImage
{
    public string SomeName { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

and use Model Iterator variant item to iterate over the `Images` property. Like this:

[image]

The other option is to override the `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Services.PropertyExtractor` and `handle List<string>`.

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I also tried to use Scriban as well. I wanted to print the HeroTitle property like {{o_model.HeroTitle}} but it shows no result. Any thoughts? –

Comment: Can we do the same thing using Scriban?

Comment: @OwaisAhmed Yes, it is possible. I added an answer to your second question.

Comment: How can i get the result count in the Model Iterator, depending on the count we want to show different look and feel